# How do I display voltage on a Keysight DSOX1204G?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope, voltage-measurement

On page 37 of the manual, It clearly indicates the voltage in the top left hand corner of the screen

[DSOX1204G manual](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/9018-04786/user-manuals/9018-04786.pdf?success=true)

and hints that it would display the voltage for each channel next to the channel number.

But my screen does not show that. My screen has a 500ma reading in that position, and that appears to be miliamp, but does not update then I turn my DC benchtop power supply on and run 3.3v through it. It doesn't appear to have any reading on amps.

How do I get to voltage on my DSXO1204G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to configure the unit of the DCO channels to either *voltage* or *current*.

See page 38 of the user manual:

> In the Channel menu, the Probe softkey opens the Channel Probe menu.
> This menu lets you select additional probe parameters such as attenuation factor and units of measurement for the connected probe.

Table 5 Probe Features

> Channel units: **[1/2/3/4] > Probe > Units** (Volts, Amps)

The chapter *Measurements*, starting on page 63, describes the features of measuring input channels.

Table 19 (page 64)

> Voltage measurements: **[Meas] > Type**: (Peak-Peak, Maximum, Minimum, Amplitude, Top, Base, Overshoot, Preshoot, Average, DC RMS, AC RMS), **Add Measurement**

Comment: Thank you. That did change the value to 500mv on the top left and on the top right hand side displays 5.15v. But when I adjust my voltage on my benchtop power supply, the voltage value on top left and right fail to change with adjustment until I press auto scale again. and the reading is a little off by a few millivolts. Is there a way to get a live voltage reading?

Comment: That info is on page 38 and not 42, according to the published pdf. Just FYI

Comment: @brad My bad. The link redirects me to the German user manual. I didn't realize that, and thought you posted a link to the German manual. As for your other question, I edited my answer.